# iOS: Stretching / Resizing UITableView Header As The User Drags Down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Using storyboard, I have placed an `imageView` as my `tableView's` `headerView` inside a `ViewController`.

This is how my storyboard is set up:

[image]

Depending on what data the user is viewing, the `viewController` will either show or hide the `headerView`. My question is, that when the `headerView` is visible and the user drags down on the `tableView`, **how can I have the `imageView` stick to both the `navigationBar` and the `tableView` as it resizes to cover the space in between?**

This is what it currently does:

[image]

But this is what I'm going for:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've looked at parallax libraries, but none support sectionTitles, and I'm not necessarily going for the parallax effect either. When the user scrolls up, I want it to bounce back to the regularView and not hide the headerView. Thanks!

> ### UPDATE:
>
> I have followed the advice posted by Dany below and have done the
>   following:
>
> ```
> -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {
>
> CGRect initialFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 160);
>
> if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
>
>     initialFrame.size.height =! scrollView.contentOffset.y;
>     childHeaderView.frame = initialFrame;
> } }
> ```
>
> childHeaderView is an imageView and for some reason when I drag down,
>   the image moves up (like half of it behind the navBar) and doesn't return. Any advice would be
>   greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: did u find the solutions

Answer (score 7):

I recently posted a blog post about accomplishing this using constraints which might help, turns out it was quite straight forward.

Here is the link: [Creating parallax effect on UIScrollView using constraints](http://web.archive.org/web/20160326225445/http://blog.domesticcat.com.au/ios/2014/03/19/creating-parallax-effect-on-uiscrollview-using-simple-constraints/)

Comment: That is indeed great, but it is of no use for @KingPolycon, as he is using an image at the top of a table view, and in this case it is a lot more tricky to handle - I'm still looking into it myself. Though I guess he either found a way to do it or changed drastically his approach since he posted this question :p.

Comment: @CyberDandy You are correct, the table view header view does behave differently

Comment: This is the reason one should answers along with links. The link is dead. I'm  going to downvote this. It's a 7 upvotes that is worth nothing now. I'll Upvote again when the link is back up or some sort of answer is added.

Comment: You're right about posting with links, however if you really need it, here you go: http://web.archive.org/web/20160326225445/http://blog.domesticcat.com.au/ios/2014/03/19/creating-parallax-effect-on-uiscrollview-using-simple-constraints/

Comment: OP is asking for a table header view, your answer isn't exactly relevant

Answer (score 5):

First of all you should remove the `UIImageView` from the header and add it as a simple `UIImageView` on top of the `UITableView` then since `UITableViewDelegate` protocol conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol you can implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method to check when the `tableView` is scrolling down and has a `bouncing` effect. something like this:

```
-(void)someInitMethod {
   initialFrame = yourHeaderView.frame;
}
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
       initialFrame.size.height -= scrollView.contentOffset.y;
       yourHeaderView.frame = initialFrame;
    }
}
```

Also make sure you set the proper `contentMode` for your `UIImageView`. Also I think this implementation will create a bouncing effect but I'm not sure because I can't test it right now but I think this is a good start point for you.

Comment: Hey Dany thanks for your time! I have followed your advice and have tried what you recommended. For some reason though, as I drag down, the image just disappears, and never returns. The bouncing effect is implemented which I like though. Any suggestions? I have updated my question to show you what I tried.

Comment: Please check the `  initialFrame.size.height -= scrollView.contentOffset.y;` I think there is a `+` instad of `-` but I'm not sure. So first check the image view frame in `scrollViewDidScroll` and after that if everything is correct check if there is a need for `setNeedsDisplay` on imageView to redraw the image.

Comment: @user1886754 check my comment

Comment: The math is incorrect, this would make it look jerky as it keeps adding up to bigger and bigger number instead of increments of the difference.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I achieved it, in my case I was using a map view up the top:

1. Create a View Controller in storyboard.
2. Add a Table View and set the constraints to 0 from all sides.
3. Add a Map View (or whatever view) below the Table View so that it will get rendered over the top. It will look like it is overlapping.
4. Add constraints to the top left and right.
5. In the view controller `viewDidLoad` add the following: `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(200, 0, 0, 0)` where `200` is the height of the View. This will push the contents of the table view downwards.
6. In the view controller add the following code, which resizes the view based on the scrolling:

   ```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       var scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
       var headerFrame = mapView.frame
       if (scrollOffset < 0) {
           // Adjust map
           headerFrame = CGRect(x: mapView.frame.origin.x,
               y: mapView.frame.origin.y,
               width: mapView.frame.size.width,
               height: -scrollOffset)
       } else {
           // Adjust map
           headerFrame = CGRect(x: mapView.frame.origin.x,
               y: mapView.frame.origin.y,
               width: mapView.frame.size.width,
               height: 0)
       }
       mapView.frame = headerFrame
   }
   ```

If I could set `contentInset` from the storyboard it would be even more pretty

Comment: Need to set a clear background color to the table view as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this https://github.com/matteogobbi/MGSpotyViewController  which implements the same effect as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The earlier solutions on this page gave me some trouble when I needed this to work along with section titles and index bar, so I came up with the following alternative myself. Please note; I don't use autolayout in my project and I've only tested this on iOS9+;

**In your project's storyboard:**

1. Create a UITableView within a UIViewController (or try it with a UITableViewController).
2. Drop a UIView at the top (but within) the UITableView, so it becomes a table header above the first cell.
3. Give this header view a desired height (like 200px for example) and set the background color to "Clear Color". The Clear Color is important, the view needs to be see-through.
4. Drop a 2nd UIView within the table header UIView and make it the same size as it's parent. This will be the actual header, so feel free to give it any color, setup an image view or other content.
5. Connect this 2nd UIView to your UIViewController IBOutlet, I named it "headerView" in my case.

**Next, go to your UIViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Remove view from table header and place it in the background instead.
    [self.headerView removeFromSuperview];
    UIView *backgroundView = [UIView new];
    [backgroundView addSubview:self.headerView];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    /* Set initialScrollOffset ivar to start offset, because in my case
       the scroll offset was affected by the statusbar + navigation bar heights
       and the view controller's "extend edges under top bars" option. */
    initialScrollOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    /* Modify headerView height only if the table content gets pulled
       beyond initial offset. */
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < initialScrollOffset) {
        CGRect frame = self.headerView.frame;
        frame.size.height = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height + -scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        self.headerView.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

I needed this implementation only for a stretching header with background color and labels. It should be easy to add a UIImageView to this header though.

Also, steps 1 to 5 are completely optional of course. You can programmatically create your header view or use a XIB instead. As long as you make sure the table has a Clear Colored header view set with the same height as your desired header because this serves as a spacer to keep your cells and section titles in line.

**EDIT:**

I found an even cleaner way to accomplish this;

1. Build up your table header in interface builder as described above: 1 UIView as container with a 2nd UIView embedded within.
2. Skip the `viewDidLoad` code above, there is no need to pull the UIView out of it's container and we won't need to set it as a table background.
3. Change the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method to this:

**UIViewController.m:**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
      if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < initialScrollOffset) {
           CGRect frame = self.headerView.frame;
           frame.size.height = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
           frame.origin.y = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.origin.y + scrollView.contentOffset.y;
           self.headerView.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

That's it. Only visual difference from the other solution is that the contents will now scroll up along with the rest of the cells instead of being overlapped by them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if this would help you or not ..

Set your scroll delegate to self.

and then implement this:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollOffset == 0)
    {
        // then we are at the top
    }
    else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight)
    {
        // then we are at the end
        // Do what you need here 
    }
}
```